# How to handle multiple inputs into the same object with react?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I have the following state object and form. The state gets updated with the handleEducationChange function. It works just fine. However, after the user submits the values, I'd like to give him the ability to render additional values that get 'appended' to the current values in the object. I do not know how many times the user might want to add values to that object. Is there a way to do so in react? I might be overcomplicating things but I can't think of a better solution.

```
const [educationValues, setEducationValues] = useState({
    university: "",
    degree: "",
    educationStart: "",
    educationEnd: "",
  });


function handleEducationChange(e) {
    setEducationValues({
      ...educationValues,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }

<TextField
          id="university"
          label="University"
          variant="standard"
          name="university"
          value={educationValues.university}
          onChange={handleEducationChange}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          id="degree"
          label="Degree"
          variant="standard"
          name="degree"
          value={educationValues.degree}
          onChange={handleEducationChange}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          id="education-start"
          label="Year You Begun Studies"
          variant="standard"
          name="educationStart"
          value={educationValues.educationStart}
          onChange={handleEducationChange}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          id="education-end"
          label="Year You Ended Studies"
          variant="standard"
          name="educationEnd"
          value={educationValues.educationEnd}
          onChange={handleEducationChange}
        />
        <br />
        {!addMoreEducation && (
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            type="click"
            onClick={handleFirstEducationSubmit}
          >
            Submit Education Info
          </Button>
          {addMoreEducation && <Result values={educationValues}></Result>}
```

I've tried creating a conditionally rendered component  that renders the current values input by the user and is supposed to clean the values saved in the form so that the user may use it again but I do not know if that's feasible.

```
export default function Result(props) {

  const educationValues = Object.entries(props.values);

  console.log(educationValues);
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {educationValues.map((value, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{value}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You would need to create another form to set the values of your TextField component props (name, label, id, etc) since you will have no other way of knowing what the values mean for your code once user submit them. For each new TextField form submitted, you can rerender your component to display a map of the new custom fields (array of TextField "settings" to render).